# Vagrant box can't ping host

Tags: linux, vagrant

I have a Vagrant box with public network configured.

What I can do:

- from vbox ping another machine on the network
- from another machine on the network ping the vbox
- from host ping another machine on the network
- from another machine on the network ping the host

What I can't do:

- from vbox ping the host
- from host ping the vbox

This is my Vagrantfile network part:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", auto_config: false
config.vm.provision "shell",
  run: "always",
  inline: "ifconfig eth1 192.168.0.20 netmask 255.255.255.0 up"
```

Not sure what I did wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, it should work with that. Anyway if that doesn't work perhaps the error is somewhere else in your Vagrantfile. Try manually setting the ip.

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.23"
```

This is how I do in my vagrant box and works fine. Hope this help you.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work. The only thing I can think of is in vbox I see two ethernet adapters. eth0 is the old one with previous private network. eth1 is the one with the public IP address. I wonder how I can get rid of the private one and replace it with the public one.